# Pre-deployment process for downmerging master

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm looking for a pre-deployment process that might exist in the release pipeline or the build pipeline for automatically downmerging master upon pull request completion. This would keep QA branches from getting too far out of sync when people forget to downmerge master before completing a PR into one of our QA branches.

This is the flow I'm looking for:

1. PR is completed from feature branch into QA branch
2. Upon completion, master branch is downmerged into feature branch
3. Build pipeline is run
4. Release pipeline is run

or:

1. PR is completed from feature branch into QA branch
2. Build pipeline is run
3. Upon completion, master branch is downmerged into feature branch
4. Release pipeline is run

Comment: How should this treat branches that are still just local, and haven't been pushed elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the steps below to implement your second flow.

1. Create a pipeline to create a PR which will merge from master branch into feature branch. We will use a third-party extension [Create Pull Request](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.CreatePullRequest). Assign your build service account `<project name> Build Service (<org name>)` with "Contribute to pull requests" permission of your repo.
2. Set your build pipeline as the pipeline resource to trigger the above pipeline.

The yaml file for your reference:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: CI-default # Name of the pipeline resource.
    source: CI-default # The name of the pipeline referenced by this pipeline resource.
    trigger: true # Run app-ci pipeline when any run of security-lib-ci completes

steps:
- task: CreatePullRequest@1
  inputs:
    repoType: 'Azure DevOps'
    repositorySelector: 'currentBuild'
    sourceBranch: 'master'
    targetBranch: 'feature1'
    title: 'Update feature branches'
    linkWorkItems: false
    autoComplete: true
```

Setting `autoComplete` to `true` will complete the PR automatically. You can see that the PR is created and completed by your Build Service account.